# Override has_many << function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, ruby-on-rails-2, model-associations

I have some classes in a **Rails 2** application: a `Group` have some `group_items`. Each `group_item` has a polymorphic `ìtem` : `user` or `contact`.

```
class Group < AR::Base
  has_many :group_items
  has_many :users,    :through => :group_items
  has_many :contacts, :through => :group_items
end

class GroupItem < Ar::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :item, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :users :conditions =>
      [ "#{GroupItem.table_name}.item_type = ? ", User.to_s ],
      :foreign_key => 'item_id'
  belongs_to :contacts :conditions =>
      [ "#{GroupItem.table_name}.item_type = ? ", Contact.to_s ],
      :foreign_key => 'item_id'
  validates_presence_of :group_id, :item_id, :item_type
end
```

Everything works perfectly. But I would be able to use this functions :

```
@my_group.users << @my_user
@my_group.contacts << @my_contact
```

The association seems to be too complicated to do this :

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid for GroupItem: item_type must be filled
```

Is there any way to use this function, like override the `Group` `users<<` function ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a beautiful solution, using Association Extensions

```
has_many :users, :through => :group_items do
  def <<(user)
    group_item = proxy_owner.group_items.create({ :item => user })
    return false if !group_item.valid?
    return proxy_target
  end
end
```

Comment: feels awkward to me: if item doesn't pass validation, you can't even access it to see the errors

Comment: @apneadiving It's just to have the same behavior than the original `<<`, which returns `false` when item can not be inserted.